# the top bar in the web view top but mobile bottom instead of top

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

i would like to have the header "top bar" in the web view above. But in the mobile not top but bottom. How does that work?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use position: fixed to do this.

```
.top-bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;

  @include breakpoint(medium) {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```